# Can I disable Python dynamic garbage collection?

Tags: python

Can I disable Python dynamic garbage collection?

If so, how would one go about accomplishing this goal?

Thank you for insights and guidance.

Comment: The documentation for the module `gc` outlines this. Note though that this is not usually a good idea unless you can guarantee that you won't have any reference cycles.

Comment: Understood.  I'll probably totally mess it up... Thanks a ton for the feedback...  Needing to try to get Python looking like a compiled language for safety critical purposes, so giving it a go.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To disable garbage collection, you can use the `gc` module

```
import gc
gc.disable()
```

To re-enable it, use

```
gc.enable()
```

[Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html)